# why getchar() storing duplicate values in 2d array?

Tags: c

So basically i was trying to store a character at 6th position in every row and i have succeeded with it but i am getting same value stored twice in the desired location and its succeeding location.

I don't know what is going wrong.

- I have tried using while ((getchar()) != '\n');  <-- Doesn't help
- Put getchar() before scanf
- And last , getchar() after scanf which atleast allows me to input value , the above two just prints empty array

Edit 1
- Changed columns from 5 to 6 as "chux" said prev values were resulting in outside allocation.
Edit 2
- Scroll down for working code and last error

```
    char *arr_input(int limit){
        char *p=(char*)malloc(limit*6*sizeof(char)); // Edit 1
        int i=0,j;
        //while ((getchar()) != '\n');
        while(i<limit){
            getchar();
            scanf("%c",&p[i*5+5]);    

            i++;
        }

        arr_display(p,limit);
        return p;
    }
```

```
Value at row 0 is = 
Value at row 0 is = 
Value at row 0 is = 
Value at row 0 is = 
Value at row 0 is = 
Value at row 0 is = 1
Value at row 1 is = 1
Value at row 1 is = 
Value at row 1 is = 
Value at row 1 is = 
Value at row 1 is = 
Value at row 1 is = 2
Value at row 2 is = 2
Value at row 2 is = 
Value at row 2 is = 
Value at row 2 is = 
Value at row 2 is = 
Value at row 2 is = 3
Input Verified
```

Output when declaring using calloc()

```
Value at row 0 is = 0
Value at row 0 is = 
Value at row 0 is = 
Value at row 0 is = 
Value at row 0 is = 
Value at row 0 is = 1
Value at row 1 is = 
Value at row 1 is = 0
Value at row 1 is = 
Value at row 1 is = 
Value at row 1 is = 
Value at row 1 is = 2
Value at row 2 is = 
Value at row 2 is = 
Value at row 2 is = 0
Value at row 2 is = 
Value at row 2 is = 
Value at row 2 is = 3
```

Working Code except the calloc() is not initializing 0 value so i did manually

```
    char *arr_input(int limit){
        char *p=(char*)calloc(limit*6,sizeof(char));
        int i=0;
        while(i<limit){
            scanf(" %c",&p[i*6+5]);             
            i++;
        }
        zeroIn(p,limit);
        arr_display(p,limit);
        return p;
    }
    void *zeroIn(char *p ,int limit){
        int i=0,j=0;
        for(i=0;i<limit;i++){
            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
                p[i*6+j]='0';
        }       
            //arr_display(p,limit); 
    }
    char *arr_display(char *disp,int size){
        int i=0,j=0;
        for (i = 0; i <size ;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<6;j++){
         printf("Value at row %d is = %c\n",i,disp[i*6+j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
Value at row 0 is = 0
Value at row 0 is = 0
Value at row 0 is = 0
Value at row 0 is = 0
Value at row 0 is = 0
Value at row 0 is = 1
Value at row 1 is = 0
Value at row 1 is = 0
Value at row 1 is = 0
Value at row 1 is = 0
Value at row 1 is = 0
Value at row 1 is = 2
Value at row 2 is = 0
Value at row 2 is = 0
Value at row 2 is = 0
Value at row 2 is = 0
Value at row 2 is = 0
Value at row 2 is = 3
```

Comment: `&p[i*5+5]` is outside allocation.

Comment: Still it is storing duplicate values

Comment: Keep in mind that `malloc` is not setting memory to zero. Use `calloc` instead.

Comment: And why are you using both `getchar` and `scanf`?

Comment: You probably want an array of pointers to strings instead of this.

Comment: I am using getchar() so that it removes the '\n' value from buffer @JUSHJUSH.

Comment: @Lundin can you elaborate more please?

Comment: @Pratik use `scanf(" %c", ...)` to skip \n (whitespace before character)

Comment: Please, can you show `arr_display` function?

Comment: @JUSHJUSH Thank you very much. It helped :). Wait i will update question

Comment: @Pratik `char* array [n];` is much easier to work with and can be used in case the different strings have variable lengths.

Comment: @Pratik Your last output seems good, what do you expect?

Comment: @Lundin i want to convert the input number to binary form later that is why i have used 2d char array and later i will compare each input and sort them according to number of one's. i don't know what ---char* array [n];--- means

Comment: @JUSHJUSH I am making a Quine Mcclusky function simplifier as my 1st college project

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight Just call first function

Answer (score 0):

Use calloc instead of malloc. So that memory will be initialized to zero.

Please don't forget to update the allocation size (ie, 6) and the index calculation to same number. You have allocated 6, but used &p[i*5+5].

Pasted the two changes,

```
char *p=(char*)calloc(limit*6, sizeof(char)); 
scanf("%c",&p[i*6+5]);
```

Comment: I don't have to use getchar() then?

Comment: i have posted the output when using calloc instead of malloc